# Loading UV map into UV/Image Editor

Tags: uv, interface, uv-image-editor

Its probably a very stupid question but i dont know the answer
[image]

On the right you can see a UV map and probably i am too stupid to find the button that loads the uv map into the UV/Image editor.

Comment: Just enter *Edit Mode*

Comment: you should also load an image